# Auto-generated row on Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, arduino-uno, time-and-attendance

I am currently working on fingerprint-based student attendance system. I am using Arduino Uno and fingerprint sensor to get student attendance record and store in SQL Server. I have a table called `Attendance` in my database which is storing student attendance records.But I have a problem with that.

Lets say **Student A** is **absent** today, the attendance record will not be stored in table `Attendance` for Student A. Meaning that I can only show students who are **present** to school today, the attendance record for Student A cannot be shown to the teachers.

Teachers can only view student attendance record after selecting the date, Student A attendance record cannot be seen by teachers cause there is no records for Student A in table `Attendance`

So How can I solve this? Any suggestion or reference? Your help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You use a left join from the table of students to your attendance table.

Comment: @SeanLange But teachers can only view student attendance after selecting date which is a column in table `Attendance`. That means I can't show **Student A** attendance record to teachers too

Comment: use the parameter in the join clause, not your where clause. `left join attendance on <...> and @AttendanceDate = someColumn`

Comment: Huh??? Are you saying they want to view a given students attendance on a certain day and they can't select the date because the student doesn't have an entry for that day? Sounds like you need to rethink some stuff.

Comment: Just put the date check in the "on" clause of the left outer join (not the "where") clause. Otherwise you're effectively negating the "left" qualifier of the "left join"

Comment: @SeanLange System should be able to show all student attendance records, but for me I can't show Student A attendance record because there is no record being stored in table `Attendance` for Student A. When teachers wanted to view attendance record, they need to choose the date (a column in table `Attendance`) . So I can't really show the attendance records for those who are absent

Comment: @Xedni Ya, I put my date check in the WHERE clause. Do you have any example for putting date check in ON CLAUSE?

Comment: Don't use the Attendance table to select the date. You should have a calendar table with all potential dates.

Comment: @Conard, I posted an example as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're passing in the date as a parameter, you can just `left outer join` to the attendance table, and put the date check in the `on` clause (as opposed to the `where` clause. Putting it in the `where` clause effectively turns a `left outer join` into an `inner join`, due to the order in which the query is parsed and executed.

```
select * 
from [student] s
left outer join [attendance] a
    on s.[id] = a.[id]
        and a.[attendanceRecordDate] = @date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM STUDENT
LEFT JOIN ATTENDANCEMARK
ON STUDENT.ID = ATTENDANCEMARK.STUDENTID
WHERE ATTENDANCEMARK.DATE = @DATE OR ATTENDANCEMARK.DATE IS NULL
```

Explanation: you are looking to list all students with today's attendance mark, but want to list all students even if they have no attendance mark.